# Audio garbled (also causes video stutter) when outputting sound via GPUs HDMI

Tags: audio, graphics-card, motherboard, hdmi, gpu

When I output sound through the HDMI port on my GPU, sometimes the sound comes out all garbled (It sometimes returns to normal after a while, sometimes it doesn't). The best way I can describe it is that it turns human voices into the demonic screams of the dead. If I load a YouTube video and this happens, it also causes the video to stutter and lag. When the audio becomes clear again, the video is out of sync with the audio.

Outputting sound to my speaker via the motherboard output on the front or rear of my case solves the problem (So it isn't a massive problem, it just inconveniences me because I need more wires trailing around my desk).

**Note** - This question may be related to my previous question. I'm not sure whether the issues are related, but I'll leave the link here in case someone wants to investigate further - [GPU struggles only in the primary PCIe slot, is this a motherboard issue?](https://superuser.com/questions/1521215/gpu-struggles-only-in-the-primary-pcie-slot-is-this-a-motherboard-issue?noredirect=1#comment2304285_1521215)

**Specs:**

- Mobo - Asus Z97-AR
- GPU - Gtx 960

Comment: Can you try downloading a youtube video that exhibits the problem, then play it from an offline video player like VLC? It would be good to find out if specific video codecs cause the issue. You can also use YouTube's "Stats for Nerds" menu to see the codecs on videos that do it. -- Also, there is a small possibility that your previous problems with power shortages could have done some damage to the GPU.

Comment: @Romen. It doesn't seem to be a specific type of video. I've just tried a couple of offline videos I have in .avi and .mp4. Both of them have the same issue when using GPU audio through HDMI.

Comment: It's not that it only happens sometimes in the sense that it happens on different videos. It's that it happens sometimes in the sense that sometimes a video will load perfectly, other times I get problems, with the same video.

Comment: OK, when the HDMI sound is being used: What is the desktop resolution, colour depth, and refresh rate? What are the HDMI audio output's channels & sample rate set to?

Comment: @Romen. 3840 x 2160. 24-bit colour depth I think. 60Hz. How would I go about finding the HDMI audio output's channels and sample rate?

Comment: I should note, this issue doesn't just happen with this monitor.

Comment: In the sound device properties: Right click the sound icon in the system tray -> "Playback Devices" or "Sound Settings". If you're on Windows 10 you need to find the Windows 7 style menu that listed the playback devices. select the HDMI out and go to "Advanced" tab.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103899/discussion-between-romen-and-cutter).

Comment: If your sound issue is unrelated to the GPU as you mentioned in other comments, then it could be due to a high latency from the OS's mechanism for processing sound, or CPU usage issue. You can test the "DPC Latency" with [LatencyMon](https://www.resplendence.com/latencymon). For CPU usage, keep an eye on task manager when the audio distorts to see if there's a CPU spike.

Answer (score 1):

A bad HDMI cable or one that is not rated for HDMI 2.0 (*you mentioned 3840x2160 in comments*) could cause an issue like this.
Try switching the cable and see whether that solves the problem.

Comment: Okay nope... It's still happening... This is driving me mad!